# Php Elasticsearch with query parameters

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a host for Elasticsearch set up like this 199.55.56.289:9998.
What i need is to make a post with Json body but to also add several custom search query's on that host URL so it looks something like this:
199.55.56.289:9998/archive/blog?param1=0&param2=150&param3=0

Is there a way to add those 3 query params in json body when making a post request?
in this case i know that

```
$query = 
[
    index: archive,
    type: blog
    ...
]
```

but what can i do with those uri params?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch supports uri search, So you can use it like this

```
<?php

$query = 'event:played AND a:b AND @timestamp:c';

$finalUrl = '199.55.56.289:9998/archive/blog?q='.urlencode($query);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$finalUrl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$output=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output.PHP_EOL;
```

Check Here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/search-search.html#search-api-query-params-q